# Find URL Inside a [code] and [php] tag

Tags: php, regex

My string is somthing like this:

```
$string = '
Link_1: [code]This is a textual line.
www.google.com
This is a textual line.[/code]

Link_2: [php]This is a textual line.
www.google.com
This is a textual line.[/php]
';
```

I want to use a REGEX so that I could replace the URL inside this string and should return like this:

```
Link_1: [code]This is a textual line.
LINK HIDDEN
This is a textual line.[/code]

Link_2: [php]This is a textual line.
LINK HIDDEN
This is a textual line.[/php]
```

I am a REGEX noob so please help me to find a correct REGEX to get the result mentioned above, thank you

Comment: Hi Avinash, I am sorry but I have no clue how to compose a REGEX for this :(

Comment: How about this http://regex101.com/r/dI1cP2/10 ?

Comment: I tried this: `$message = preg_replace("/(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)(?:[^.\s]+)(?:\.[^.\n\s]+)*\.\w{2,4}(?=(?:(?!\[/?(?:code|php)])[\S\s])*\[/(?:code|php)])/m","{$error_message_link}","{$message}");` but it hided complete string, :(

Comment: I now tried this: `$message = preg_replace("~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)(?:[^.\s]+)(?:\.[^.\n\s]+)*\.\w{2,4}(?=(?:(?!\[/?(?:code|php)])[\S\s])*\[/(?:code|php)])~","{$error_message_link}","{$message}");` and it did nothing at all :(

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookahead to check for the links which are going to be matched wouldn't be followed by a closing php or code tag.

```
$content = <<<EOS
Link_1: [code]This is a textual line.
www.google.com
This is a textual line.[/code]

Link_2: [php]This is a textual line.
www.google.com
This is a textual line.[/php]
EOS;
$needle = '~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)(?:[^.\s]+)(?:\.[^.\n\s]+)*\.\w{2,4}(?=(?:(?!\[/?(?:code|php)])[\S\s])*\[/(?:code|php)])~m';
echo preg_replace($needle,'LINK HIDDEN',$content);
```

**Output:**

```
Link_1: [code]This is a textual line.
LINK HIDDEN
This is a textual line.[/code]

Link_2: [php]This is a textual line.
LINK HIDDEN
This is a textual line.[/php]
```

Comment: Tried but it did nothing at all :(

Comment: it works for me.. There is no problem with regex, i think the problem may be in the code itself.

Comment: my [code] and [php] tags are created in such way that every link posted in them will not create a hyperlink, I mean the link is plain having no markup at all. Using your REGEX it didn't matches and replaced, is this something related to that or may be another issue?

Comment: post an example which replicate this behaviour.

Comment: See this: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0833ro7c73 Notice the link which is not hyperlinked

Comment: @user2854563, you didn't posted example string which causes problems.

Comment: @user2854563 you mean this http://regex101.com/r/tR9oZ1/1 ?